# I'm surprised they "didn't" vs "hadn't"

Tags: tense

I'm kind of confused as to which one I should use. While I'd normally opt for "didn't", I'm not sure if I could get away with "hadn't", though Google displays many results for both structures. Are there any semantic differences? Would present perfect be passable in any of those?

> I'm surprised they didn't listen to my advice.
>
> I'm surprised they hadn't listened to my advice.

Also

> I want to express my amazement that he didn't listen to me.
>
> I want to express my amazement that he hadn't listened to me.

Answer (score 3):

The past perfect is used to describe an event that occurred in the past before another event occurred.

> I **was** surprised that they **hadn't listened** to my advice.

They didn't listen to your advice, then you were surprised.  Both occurred in the past.

**Didn't** is used as past simple to describe an action that occurred in the past.  In your desired usage, you're describing your current thoughts about that past event.

> I **am** surprised that they **didn't listen** to my advice.

My surprise is occurring now due to their failure to listen in the past.

Examples:

> When I saw John this morning, he *hadn't moved* from the spot where he passed out last night.
> The sun *hadn't risen* yet when I woke up this morning.

> I just checked on John, he *didn't move* from the spot where he passed out last night.
> Is my alarm ringing?  The sun *didn't rise* yet.

I probably would have said hasn't moved and hasn't risen for these examples, but I'm trying to keep the examples parallel to one another.  They are grammatical.

Answer (score 1):

*I'm surprised he hadn't...* does not sound correct, although any English speaker would understand the meaning.

"Didn't" is the proper choice here because the person who's surprised is speaking in the present tense about a past event. "Hadn't" is correct if the speaker were surprised in the past tense about an event that was ongoing at the time.

**Speaker surprised in present tense by a specific past event**

> I'm surprised he didn't say hello.

Barbara's friend John passed her on the street but did not say hello. The not-saying-hello event occurred at a specific time.

**Speaker surprised in present tense by an ongoing condition**

> I'm surprised she hasn't said hello [yet].

Jake's new boss Emily has been at the company for three days, but she has not said hello to him *yet*. The not-saying-hello condition is ongoing; Emily can end the condition by saying hello, or prolong it by continuing to ignore Jake.

**Speaker surprised in past tense by a specific prior event**

> I was surprised he didn't say hello.

Same construction as its present tense counterpart.

**Speaker surprised in past tense by a prior ongoing condition**

> I was surprised he hadn't called me [yet].

George was waiting for a phone call from a friend. *At the time of his surprise*, George's friend hadn't called. Sometime *after* George's surprise, the friend called. If the friend never called, George would have said "didn't" instead of "hadn't."

> "What were you doing at one o'clock, George?"
>
> "I was waiting for my friend to call."
>
> "What were you doing at three o'clock?"
>
> "Still waiting. I was surprised he hadn't called yet."
>
> "And what were you doing at six o'clock?"
>
> "I was having dinner with my friend. He finally called me at four o'clock."

The ongoing condition need not have ended after the time of surprise.

> *George's friend never called*
>
> "What were you doing at three o'clock, George?"
>
> "I was waiting for my friend to call. I was surprised he hadn't called already."
>
> "And what are you doing now?"
>
> "I'm still waiting. I'm surprised he hasn't called yet."

So "hadn't" should be used when the surprise is in the past tense, and the cause of the surprise is a past event that was ongoing at the time of the surprise.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised they didn't listen vs hadn't listened to my advice.

I want to express my amazement that he didn't listen vs hadn't listened to me.

The use of the simple past "didn't listen" is grammatically correct in these sentences, whereas the use of the past perfect doesn't sound natural.

You use the past perfect when you refer to an event happened before another action in the past such as "I was surprised they hadn't listened to my advice.

On the other hand, when you refer to an event that happened before another event in the present, you can use the simple past or the present perfect such as I am surprised they didn't listen or haven't listened to my advice.

Answer (score 0):

In both these sentences, you are learning of or being told of an event that happened in the past.

> I'm surprised they didn't listen to my advice
>
> I want to express my amazement that he didn't listen to me.

The event in question is completed and no longer is happening.

> I'm surprised they hadn't listened to my advice
>
> I want to express my amazement that he hadn't listened to me.

The event in question is ongoing.

Examples:

> - He bought that car you told him not to.  It ended up being a lemon.  He took that one back, and now has a new car.
> - I'm surprised he didn't listen to my advice.  He could have avoided all that trouble.

---

> - He bought that car you told him not to.  He hates it, but he's still driving it.
> - I'm surprised he hadn't listened to my advice.  He would be much happier if he didn't buy that car.

Comment: So in fact in this specific situation I express an ongoing situation by using the past perfect form? What about present perfect? It seems to me it'd be more logical to use that tense in such cases.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of your *hadn't* examples.  In all of them I suspect that I would have used simple past (i.e. they haven't...  he hasn't...  etc.)